# Calculate product of weighted distance of path netlogo

Tags: social-networking, netlogo

I have a network of people in netlogo. In short a social network. Each social link has a trust value. when a person meets another person whom it does not know and want to make business with it , it needs to have certain recommendation.

In our case this recommendation comes from shortest path which means if "a" wants to make business with "c" and does not know it initially; it can get recommendation from a friend who knows "c". so e.g. trust value of a on c can be calculated as (trust of a on b) * (trust of b on c ).

how can i calculate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this the new network extension, `nw` (bundled with NetLogo), using [`nw:weighted-distance-to`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html#distance-to-weighted-distance-to).

Comment: thankyou bryan. but it gives us cummulative instead of product. I want the weights of social links of shortest path to be multiplied intead of summation. I wonder how to do that.

Comment: Oh I apologize, I missed that.